# docker-compose app container can't connect to mongo container

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my dotnet core project and mongodb as container services with `docker-compose`. Both services have a clean start with no errors. When I call an endpoint that interacts with mongo I get a timeout error. Since I'm using `docker-compose` I expect that I can reference the `mongo` service by the compose service name in the connection string.

`mongo:27017/api?authSource=api` with username `api` and password `password123` as seen in the docker-compose file below. Instead I get this error:

```
System.TimeoutException : A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongo:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongo:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.ResolveCallback(Object context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ResolveEndPointsAsync(EndPoint initial)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-09-03T21:28:59.1614966Z" }] }.
  Stack Trace:
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedAsync(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServerAsync(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterSeverSelctionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSessionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.DeleteOneAsync(FilterDefinition`1 filter, DeleteOptions options, Func`2 bulkWriteAsync)
   at Tests.AssetRespositoryTest.DeleteAsset(String assetId) in /app/Tests/Repository/AssetRepositoryTests.cs:line 140
   at Tests.AssetRespositoryTest.TestWithTransaction() in /app/Tests/Repository/AssetRepositoryTests.cs:line 75
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_0(Object state)
```

I've confirmed my connection string has the user/pass set to what's in the compose file below. If I `exec` into my app container I can ping the `mongo` container by service name, but I can't use the mongo shell to connect  with the `root` or `api` user instead I get this error from the mongo shell:

```
docker-compose exec app bash
mongo --host mongo --port 27017 -u api -p password123 --authenticationDatabase api

2020-09-03T20:28:37.209+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server mongo:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongo:27017 (23.217.138.110:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
```

Interestingly I can connect when running the same mongo shell connect command from my host terminal so this seems to be a container issue.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

networks:
  # This special network is configured so that the local metadata
  # service can bind to the specific IP address that ECS uses
  # in production
  credentials_network:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
          config:
              - subnet: "169.254.170.0/24"
                gateway: 169.254.170.1

services:
  # This container vends credentials to your containers
  ecs-local-endpoints:
    # The Amazon ECS Local Container Endpoints Docker Image
    image: amazon/amazon-ecs-local-container-endpoints
    volumes:
      # Mount /var/run so we can access docker.sock and talk to Docker
      - /var/run:/var/run
      # Mount the shared configuration directory, used by the AWS CLI and AWS SDKs
      # On Windows, this directory can be found at "%UserProfile%\.aws"
      - ${USERPROFILE}\\.aws:/home/.aws/
    environment:
      # define the home folder; credentials will be read from $HOME/.aws
      HOME: "/home"
      # You can change which AWS CLI Profile is used
      AWS_PROFILE: "default"
    networks:
        credentials_network:
            # This special IP address is recognized by the AWS SDKs and AWS CLI 
            ipv4_address: "169.254.170.2"

  app:
    depends_on:
      - ecs-local-endpoints
      - mongo
    networks:
      credentials_network:
        ipv4_address: "169.254.170.3"
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile.compose'
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "local"
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
      AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI: "/creds"
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
    ports:
      - 9999:9999

  mongo:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:4.2'
    restart: 'always'
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=iamroot
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=api
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=api
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mongo-express:
      image: mongo-express
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      environment:
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: iamroot
      depends_on:
        - mongo
        - app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build

WORKDIR /vsdbg
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh \
        | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg
        
# Not copying anything since it's being mounted and managed by docker-compose volumes
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1
EXPOSE 9999

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4 \
    && echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y iputils-ping mongodb-org-shell

ENTRYPOINT dotnet watch --project /app/API/src/Foo.Api/Foo.Api.csproj run --urls=http://+:9999
```

I added an xUnit test project to `exec` in and run in `app`, but I get the same time out stack trace error seen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the mongodb container to the network, and provide it's discovery alias.

```
    networks:
        credentials_network:
            # define an alias for service discovery
            aliases:
                - mongo
            ipv4_address: "169.254.170.4"
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try with yaml file `version: '3.7'`?
if still can not please try compose with no network defined.

Comment: What change from version 2 to 3 is the change you think would help here? From what I've seen it's primarily focused on swarm interop, but may be missing something.

Comment: version 3 isn't an option due to these github issues and the network configuration need:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4366
https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/1636#issuecomment-304735171
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecs-local-container-endpoints/issues/20